# Interpolate missing Data

Tags: excel, vba, linear-interpolation

I have data in excel , I need fill missing (blank) data, the input data is like:

```
row1 --> 1   2      3   blank   5   6   blank  blank   9   10

row2 --> 2   4   blank  blank   10  12    14   blank   18  blank
```

the VBA code must read each rows and fill them like :

```
row1 --> 1   2  3  4   5    6    7    8    9    10

row2 --> 2   4  6  8   10   12   14   16   18   20
```

is there clear solution to do this in VBA(excel)?

Comment: Simply select first two members of both the rows and drag it to the right !

Comment: In VBA, this is known as `AutoFill`.

Comment: @ImranMalek This isn't possible for large data!

Comment: Tnx @Dominique for give me the keyword.

Comment: @Arash why not ? you can press F5 and enter the last cell where you want this fill to be extended and press shift and then Ctrl+R .

Comment: Autofill solutions might not work if the numbers are not evenly spaced.

Comment: You might be able to use one of the `Forecast...` worksheetfunctions within VBA .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an Example for a mathematical solution:

1. Generate *x-values* `x` (we need them as array for the next 2 steps)
2. Calculate the *slope* `m` for the given row values
3. Calculate the *intercept* `c` for the given row values
4. Interpolate the missing values `y` with `y = m * x + c`

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LinearInterpolateRowWise()
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J3")

    Dim ArrX As Variant 'create an array of x-values
    ReDim ArrX(1 To 1, 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count
        ArrX(1, c) = c
    Next c

    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    For iRow = 1 To DataRange.Rows.Count 'loop row wise
        Dim Slope As Double 
        Slope = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(DataRange.Rows(iRow), ArrX)

        Dim Intercept As Double
        Intercept = Application.WorksheetFunction.Intercept(DataRange.Rows(iRow), ArrX)

        For iCol = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count 'interpolate missing values
            If DataRange.Cells(iRow, iCol) = vbNullString Then
                DataRange.Cells(iRow, iCol) = Slope * iCol + Intercept 'y = m * x + c
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

So assuming this source data
[image]

It interpolates like this
[image]

The following is a visualization of the interpolation of row 3:

[image]

So what happens is we calculate the linear equation through the given points (blue) and use it to calculate the missing point (orange).

---

This will even work for non linear original points (blue) like in the following Example.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Elegant, just elegant ...plus one

Comment: While this is a good solution to one interpretation of the problem (+1) it does assume that each row is an arithmetic sequence with missing values. While this is true of OP's mock example, it might not be true for OP's actual use-case. There might nor be a single slope for each row.

Comment: @JohnColeman Since the OP asked for a *linear interpolation* there is no need for an *arithmetic sequence* this will still interpolate linear on any given values. See my added visualizations. But I agree that the OP was not clear about if he wants to interpolate linear through the whole data row or just linear between the 2 data point right/left of the blank.

Comment: Again, it is a question of interpretation. You are still assuming that each row should be fit to a line. "Linear interpolation" could mean fitting a line through two known points which straddle one or more unknown points and using that line segment to give values to the unknown values. In your final graph you are doing regression rather than interpolation. In any event, I upvoted your original answer and fault OP rather than you in not being (in my perhaps pedantic mind) clear enough.

Comment: nicely laid out +