# how to linearly interpolate in excel based on empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, interpolation, linear-interpolation

The first macro runs a predefined check in order to find gaps in the data set y and z: we have data x which is the order running from 1-7. The values y and z are the values with gaps which are subject to interpolation with respect to x (order number).

The solution is presented below

e.g:

```
x     y    z  
1     2    3    
2     4    6    
3     ?    8  ' interpolation of y  between x=2 and x=4    
4     8    ?  ' interpolation of z between x=3 and x= 5    
5     12   14
```

Edited version 2

```
Public Sub Interpol_Klicken()

Dim i As Long
Dim x1 As Double
Dim x2 As Double
Dim y1 As Double
Dim y2 As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim rngY As Range
Dim iCol  As Long
Dim iRow  As Long

Set rngY = Worksheets("Z").Range("A1:D10")

 iRow = rngY.Rows.Count
 iCol = rngY.Columns.Count


 For iCol = 2 To rngY.Columns.Count
 For iRow = 2 To rngY.Rows.Count

 If rngY.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "" Then

 y2 = rngY.Cells(iRow, iCol).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value
 y1 = rngY.Cells(iRow, iCol).Offset(RowOffset:=-1).Value

 x2 = rngY.Cells(iRow, 1).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value
 x1 = rngY.Cells(iRow, 1).Offset(RowOffset:=-1).Value
 x = rngY.Cells(iRow, 1).Value

 rngY.Cells(iRow, iCol) = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)

 End If
 Next iRow
 Next iCol


 End Sub
```

Comment: This [Interpolate missing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554615/interpolate-missing-data/53555197#53555197) might give you an idea (actually the answer does a linear regression to interpolate the missing data). It is a similar (or even duplicate) question.

Comment: You can also look into `Forecast.Ets` function which has various options on how to deal with missing data points in a series. @Pᴇʜ, awesome solution tho! +1 for proper self promotion ;)

Comment: Hi Peh, thanks for the quick reply. In fact, I have got two rows of data x=timeseries going from 1 day to 10 Years (discontinuously) and the corresponding variables y=interest rates. If one interest rate is missing, lets say at 6Months that rate would need to be interpolated by take one data point to the right (which is 3Months) and to the left (which is 12 Months) of the missing data. Can your provided example be used for that case as well, when you have two dependent variables? Thanx

Comment: @YavuzTopal It's the same approach. My example uses *all* given data points to emulate the missing ones. If you want only the ones *left* and *right* just use only these 2 points to calculate slope and intersect.

Comment: you are right. my mistake. I have just seen it. Thank you for the advice. Shall I delete my post as it appears to be a duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolate missing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554615/interpolate-missing-data)

Comment: @YavuzTopal I started close-voting as duplicate. So the question remains but will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Peh, Thank you. Could you quick tell me what factor in your code needs to be modified as to consider not the entire code but only the right and the left values to the blank?

Comment: find the cell/range with missing data eg `MyMissing`  and then expand it to the left and right `MyMissing.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Resize(ColumnResize:=MyMissing.Columns.Count + 2)` and use it instead of the original data points `DataRange.Rows(iRow)`. Instead of generating x values `ArrX` you should use the x values of your data (if you have).

Comment: @Peh. I have posted an edited version of my code above and tried to implement the interpolation method 'y=y1 + (y2 – y1) * (x – x1) / (x2 – x1) with y being the missing component. I just doubt that it is will work I am sure there is something missing.

Comment: @YavuzTopal can you provide a [mcve] with full example data. And a screenshot of your sheet (including some sentences of description) would also help a lot to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Peh: I guess i have found the solution to my problem myself. A review and your thoughts are still welcomed. Thank you